# Error when creating a directory with C++ and Boost

Tags: c++, macos, boost, directory, macports

I'm trying to create a directory in C++ (compiling with Clang) on Mac Yosemite with Boost (Boost was installed via Macports). This is what my code looks like:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp> // header at top of file

boost::filesystem::path path("/Users/u5305887/Desktop/ti"); // code in main function
boost::filesystem::create_directories( path );
```

However, when I compile it, I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)"

I've been trying to Google this error but I can't seem to find any way to fix it. I've double checked my code against a few tutorials and can't see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: soooo "Error when not creating a directory", actually

Comment: Well, error trying to create a directory I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to link against the boost libraries. E.g. for clang you'd add

```
-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

to your linking step.

Comment: ah damn I'd forgotten to add that to my makefile, thank-you so much!